# Flatten a List Python

Tags: python

Consider a List that has a several nested list inside it.

```
['String example 1',
'String example 2',
['String example 3'],
['String example 4', 'String example 5'],
'String example 6']
```

The output should be

```
['String example 1',
'String example 2',
'String example 3',
'String example 4',
'String example 5',
'String example 6',]
```

I've use this code but the problem it also flatten a non nested string

```
flat_list = [num for sublist in text for num in sublist]
```

Comment: one of the easiest way is to use - `sum(sublist,[])`

Comment: @Vaebhav It wont work cuz there are strings

Comment: Before asking a question, please search for existing Q&As.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it. Check if the datatype of the item is a list or not. If it's not then append it directly. But if it's a list then append by looping through its items. :

```
flat_list = []
for sublist in text:
    if type(sublist) == list:
        for num in sublist:
            flat_list.append(num)
        
    else:
        flat_list.append(sublist)
```

Output:

```
['String example 1', 'String example 2', 'String example 3', 'String example 4', 'String example 5', 'String example 6']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isinstance(..., list)` to check whether an item is a list, and then flatten the sublist:

```py
lst = ['String example 1',
'String example 2',
['String example 3'],
['String example 4', 'String example 5'],
'String example 6']

def flatten(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x

output = list(flatten(lst))
print(output)
# ['String example 1', 'String example 2', 'String example 3', 'String example 4', 'String example 5', 'String example 6']
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @j1-lee 's answer, but using `yield` function (for recursion!) might be a bit confusing. Here is a more beginner-friendly version:

```
def flatten(lst):
    new_lst = []
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            new_lst += flatten(x)
        else:
            new_lst.append(x)
    return new_lst
```